# window.onerror get Element target

Tags: javascript, onerror

how to get element target in the event error in javascript?

source:

```
<button onclick="a(this);">GO!</button>
<script>
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
  console.log(error.stack); // event.target = window
}
</script>
```

out:

> ReferenceError: a is not defined
>
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (onerror.html:1)

what this is "HTMLButtonElement.onclick" ?

```
var domID = "HTMLButtonElement".id;
addLog(document.querySelector(domID)); //example usage
```

Comment: There is no way to get the element from the onerror.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would strongly recommend you don't use inline onclick event handlers, due to the issue you're having - they're incredibly hard to debug and don't promote seperation of concerns (html is for markup, js files are for logic).

Secondly, overwriting the onerror handler is also risky as you don't know what third party code (if any) might be expecting from the onerror handler. This is the same as the rules of "Don't override base objects eg. `Array.map = function() {};`

However, the way to get the element in this case would be to write the event handler in a different way to capture the error and re-throw with the element information available.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    try {
        a(this);
    } catch (e) {
        e.message = e.message + " - element clicked: " + this.id;
        throw e;
    }
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xhtvhry/2/) showing an example.

Comment: As per the documentation, it prevents calling the default handler only when returning true. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#window.onerror